# Инициализация AudioRecord

Tags: android, android-audio-record

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь инициализировать AudioRecord на Samsung Galaxy S5 и ZTE T82 Grand X, но получаю одну и ту же ошибку. Для инициализации использую вот этот метод:

```
public void createAudioRecorder(){
    int[] rates = {8000, 11025, 22050,44100, 48000, 96000 };
    int[] chans = {AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO};
    int[] encs  = {AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT};

for(int enc : encs)
{
    for(int ch : chans)
    {
        for(int rate : rates)
        {
            int t = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, ch, enc);
            Log.d(TAG, "MinBufferSize: " + t);

            if((t != AudioRecord.ERROR) && (t != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE))
            {
                audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                        rate, ch, enc, t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Соответственно ошибка:

```
2-20 23:41:17.575 10595-10595/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whatever.soundreplayer/com.whatever.soundreplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 96000Hz is not a supported sample rate.
```

Если я убираю 96000 из rates[] то получаю уже вот эту ошибку:

```
02-20 23:43:51.940 10822-10822/com.whatever.soundreplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord
```

Якобы не инициализировалась AudrioRecord, однако ошибку я свою понять не могу.
Вот весь мой лог:

```
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] getMinBufferSize(): Invalid audio format.
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: -2
02-20 23:43:49.528 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 640
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 640
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 640
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 7680
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 7680
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 1280
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 1280
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 1280
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 7680
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: MinBufferSize: 7680
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for record source 1
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? E/AudioRecord-Java: [ android.media.AudioRecord ] Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
02-20 23:43:49.608 10822-10822/? D/myLogs: init state = 0
02-20 23:43:49.618 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15842: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.getLayoutDirection ()I
02-20 23:43:49.618 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15846: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.resolveLayoutDirection (I)V
02-20 23:43:49.618 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15847: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setLayoutDirection (I)V
02-20 23:43:49.618 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15848: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setMarginEnd (I)V
02-20 23:43:49.618 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15849: Landroid/view/ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams;.setMarginStart (I)V
02-20 23:43:49.638 10822-10822/? I/Adreno200-EGLSUB: <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
02-20 23:43:49.648 10822-10822/? D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5bfc0000 size:1949696 offset:0 fd:59

                                             [ 02-20 23:43:49.648 10822:0x2a46 E/         ]
                                             Can't open file for reading

                                             [ 02-20 23:43:49.658 10822:0x2a46 E/         ]
                                             Can't open file for reading
02-20 23:43:49.658 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15428: Landroid/view/Gravity;.apply (IIILandroid/graphics/Rect;IILandroid/graphics/Rect;I)V
02-20 23:43:49.658 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15432: Landroid/view/Gravity;.applyDisplay (ILandroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;I)V
02-20 23:43:49.658 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16514: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.hasOverlappingRendering ()Z
02-20 23:43:49.658 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
02-20 23:43:49.658 10822-10822/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16523: Landroid/widget/ImageView;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
02-20 23:43:49.708 10822-10822/? D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c3ec000 size:1949696 offset:0 fd:63
02-20 23:43:51.920 10822-10822/com.whatever.soundreplayer D/memalloc: ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5c6c8000 size:1949696 offset:0 fd:67
02-20 23:43:51.940 10822-10822/com.whatever.soundreplayer D/myLogs: record start
02-20 23:43:51.940 10822-10822/com.whatever.soundreplayer W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abf9d8)
02-20 23:43:51.940 10822-10822/com.whatever.soundreplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
                                                                            at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:516)
                                                                            at com.whatever.soundreplayer.MainActivity.recordStart(MainActivity.java:107)
                                                                            at com.whatever.soundreplayer.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:45)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3518)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14135)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Тут суть в том, что разные устройства должны иметь разные настройки инициализации. 
Воспользуйтесь методом:

```
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[] { 8000, 11025, 22050, 44100 };
public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
    for (short audioFormat : new short[] { AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT }) {
        for (short channelConfig : new short[] { AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO }) {
            try {
                Log.d(C.TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: "
                        + channelConfig);
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                    if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                        return recorder;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(C.TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.",e);
            }
        }
    }
}
return null;}
```

AudioRecord recorder = findAudioRecord();
recorder.release();